# insert in multiple column with different id

Tags: php

This is what my database table looks like:

```
 id  | role    | adviser    
 1   | section |  
 2   | teacher |
```

I want to insert a new section and update the existing teacher with the adviser column. Is this possible?

Comment: What did you try? Why is this question related to PHP?

Answer (score 1):

with pdo,while you have connected successfully

```
require_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
```

And as you have get the values with select and assigned them to variables $sectionfromadviser and $teacherfromadviser you can procedure like this

```
try{

                //update the verify column from users
    $sql="UPDATE tablename SET section=:section,teacher=:teacher WHERE id = :id";


    $stmt= $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':section', $sectionfromadviser);       
    $stmt->bindParam(':teacher', $teacherfromadviser);    
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();


}catch(PDOException $e){

   if(!$stmt->execute()){

     throw $e;
   }

}catch (Exception $e) {

  throw $e;
}
```

Comment: $sectionfromadviser where it come from ?

Comment: $sql="SELECT * FROM adviser WHERE id = :id";
        $stmt= $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);
        $result= $stmt->fetch();

       $sectionfromadviser = $result['role'];

vote if it helps ! :)